# Minecraft Fabric: How to get player coordinates every tick?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to code a Minecraft mod using Fabric and the Fabric API. I am unsure of how to get the coordinates of my player every tick. I tried to use `net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity.getPos()` but that returns the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPos() from the type Entity`. How can I get my player's coordinates every tick as a variable so I can use it? I am new to the Java coding language so a detailed answer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPos() from the type Entity
```

Means you are trying to use getPos() in a static context (you are calling it on the class)

In java a Class is like an object constructor, or a "blueprint" for creating objects.

```
net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity
```

References the PlayerEntity **class**

The EntityPlayer class describes everything about the player entity and defines what it can do but is abstract, meaning that by itself it doesn't exist.

```
net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity.getPos()
```

Is (very basically) trying to get the position of the definition of what a player is.

You will need to use .getPos() on a specific PlayerEntity object.

For more about Classes and Objects: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classes-objects-java/

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that I failed to get a client instance first.

Answer (score -2):

Press F3 and see to the left there will be a part named XYZ -.   this is where you can see your cords. every tick!

Comment: I am trying to make a mod that uses the coordinates to calculate player speed. I already know how to get them through f3. Is there a way to extract data from the f3 screen so it can be used in the program?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/87835-solved-update-block-every-tick-for-grass-like-spreading/.        this is the answer